# Как добавить элементы в двусвязный список?

Tags: c++, структуры, двусвязный-список

Помогите пожалуйста дописать программу. Нужно написать процедуру, которая, получив в качестве параметра указатель на один из элементов двусвязного списка действительных чисел и два числа, добавляет первое число в начало списка, а второе в его конец. Вот мой код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct List {
    float num;
    List *next;
    List *prev;
};
List *ls = NULL;

void fill_list(){
    List *tmp, *last = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        tmp = new List;
        tmp->num = i;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if (ls == NULL)
            ls = tmp;
        else
            last->next = tmp;
        last = tmp;
    }
}

void show(){
    for (List *tmp = ls; tmp; tmp = tmp->next)
        cout << tmp->num << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void func(float a, float b){
    List *prev = NULL, *tmp;
    for (tmp = ls; tmp; prev = tmp, tmp = tmp->next)
    {

    }

}

int main()
{
    float a,b;
    fill_list();
    int sw;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "1 - show(), 2 - func(a,b), 3 - exit" << endl;
        cin >> sw;
        switch (sw) {
            case 1:
                show();
            case 2:
                cout << "Input a, b " << endl;
                cin >> a;
                cin >> b;
                func(a,b);
            case 3:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

fill_list - заполняет список, show - выводит список, func - должна добавить a в начало списка, b в конец списка

Comment: Так просто указателю PREV первого элемента задайте требуемые первый элемент.  Аналогично с next у последнего. Только не забудьте обновить указатели вставляемых элементов. Вы же понимаете, как обратиться к первому или последнему элементу списка?

Comment: И я почему-то не вижу, чтобы при заполнении списка у вас заполнялся `*prev`

Answer (score 3):

Давайте сначала пройдемся по вашим ошибкам в текущей реализации:

1. При заполнении **двусвязного** списка вы ни разу не используете `*prev`, то есть работаете с ним, как с односвязным.
2. В `case` после выполнения одного из сценариев всегда выполнится следующий, потому что вы в сценариях не используете `break`
3. В вашей реализации вы нигде не храните начало и конце списка, что повлечет за собой пробег по всем элементам списка, чтобы вставить в нужное место требуемое значение
4. У вас нигде не обрабатывается сценарий того, что список может быть изначально пустой

Ниже прилагаю вам код, где реализовано то, что вы хотели получить.

Сразу, опережая вопрос, почему мы в конец добавляем не отдельной функцией, а общей функцией добавления элемента в список `Add` - потому что `Add` всегда будет добавлять элемент в конец.
И если вы все-таки используете С++, то не понятно, зачем изобретать велосипед, когда есть готовый контейнер `list`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node                             //Структура, являющаяся звеном списка
{
    int x;                             //Значение x будет передаваться в список
    Node* Next, * Prev;                 //Указатели на адреса следующего и предыдущего элементов списка
};

class List                              //Создаем тип данных Список
{
    Node* Head, * Tail;                 //Указатели на адреса начала списка и его конца
public:
    List() :Head(NULL), Tail(NULL) {};    //Инициализируем адреса как пустые
    ~List();                           //Прототип деструктора
    void Show();                       //Прототип функции отображения списка на экране
    void Add(int x);                   //Прототип функции добавления элементов в список
    void AddFirst(int x);              //Прототип функции добавления в элемента в начало
    void func(int a, int b);           //Прототип требуемой вами функции
};

void List::func(int a, int b) {
    AddFirst(a);
    Add(b);
}

void List::AddFirst(int x) {
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->Next = NULL;                   //Указываем, что изначально по следующему адресу пусто
    temp->Prev = NULL;
    temp->x = x;
    if (Head != NULL) {                  //Если список не пустой
        temp->Next = Head;               //Указываем на предыдущий первый элемент
        Head->Prev = temp;               //Предыдущий перый элемент теперь указывает на новый первый элемент
        Head = temp;                     //Переназначаем первый элемент
    }
    else {                          //Если список пустой
        Head = Tail = temp;
    }
}

List::~List()                           //Деструктор
{
    while (Head)                       //Пока по адресу на начало списка что-то есть
    {
        Tail = Head->Next;             //Резервная копия адреса следующего звена списка
        delete Head;                   //Очистка памяти от первого звена
        Head = Tail;                   //Смена адреса начала на адрес следующего элемента
    }
}

void List::Add(int x)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;               //Выделение памяти под новый элемент структуры
    temp->Next = NULL;                   //Указываем, что изначально по следующему адресу пусто
    temp->x = x;                         //Записываем значение в структуру

    if (Head != NULL)                    //Если список не пуст
    {
        temp->Prev = Tail;               //Указываем адрес на предыдущий элемент в соотв. поле
        Tail->Next = temp;               //Указываем адрес следующего за хвостом элемента
        Tail = temp;                     //Меняем адрес хвоста
    }
    else //Если список пустой
    {
        temp->Prev = NULL;               //Предыдущий элемент указывает в пустоту
        Head = Tail = temp;              //Голова=Хвост=тот элемент, что сейчас добавили
    }
}

void List::Show()
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    //ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК С КОНЦА
    /*temp = Tail;                   //Временный указатель на адрес последнего элемента

    while (temp != NULL)               //Пока не встретится пустое значение
    {
        cout << temp->x << " ";        //Выводить значение на экран
        temp = temp->Prev;             //Указываем, что нужен адрес предыдущего элемента
    }
    cout << "\n";*/

    //ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК С НАЧАЛА
    temp = Head;                       //Временно указываем на адрес первого элемента
    while (temp != NULL)              //Пока не встретим пустое значение
    {
        cout << temp->x << " ";        //Выводим каждое считанное значение на экран
        temp = temp->Next;             //Смена адреса на адрес следующего элемента
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    List lst; //Объявляем переменную, тип которой есть список
    int sw;
    int a, b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) //Аналог нашей функции fill_list
        lst.Add(i);

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "1 - show(), 2 - func(a,b), 3 - exit" << endl;
        cin >> sw;
        switch (sw) {
            case 1:
                lst.Show();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Input a, b " << endl;
                cin >> a;
                cin >> b;
                lst.func(a, b);
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```